# Passing null to Ambigious Overloaded Method

Tags: java, overloading

Which overloaded method will be called for the below method and **why**?

I executed this code and it calls the overloaded method with List but **why does it happen?**

```
public class AmbigiousOverload {

    public static void add(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Overloaded method with Object.");
    }

    public static void add(List l) {
        System.out.println("Overloaded method with List.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(null);
    }

}
```

Output: `Overloaded method with List.`

Comment: "Which overloaded method will be called" You know which one. It's in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `List` overload is called because the `List` overload is the most specific matching overload, as all `List` implementations are subclasses of `Object`.

From [JLS Sec 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

Since any parameter you can pass to `add(List)` can also be passed to `add(Object)`, `add(List)` is more specific. As such, given that `null` can be passed to both, the more specific method is the one chosen.

Note that it wouldn't compile if you had an `add(String)` overload, since `List` and `String` are "equally" specific. (Or any other class: it doesn't have to be `String`).

Comment: How is the `List` considered specific to `Object`? `List` is an interface and not a class.

Comment: All `List` implementations are `Object`s.